# compare string sets in access

Tags: string, compare

I have a problem where I think you can also use when needed. I wish to compare word sets on separate tables identified by their `Item No` and `Order` (ordinality) and the word or value.

Here is a snapshot of the table:

[image]

Then the result I wish to accomplish was like this:

[image]

The comparison is `LIKE` rather than equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `join` and have `like` in predicate:

```
select * from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.ValueA like '%' + t2.ValueB + '%' or 
                        t2.ValueB like '%' + t1.ValueA + '%'
```

You may need use `*` instead of `%` and `&` instead of `+`. I don't remember the correct syntax for `Access`, but it is along the lines.

Comment: Thanks Giorgi. I was able to make it, using table A and B. SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM A inner join B on A.Value like '*' & B.Value & '*' or 
                  B.Value like '*' & A.Value & '*';